# Blender uninstalls itself

Tags: osx

I have to redownload Blender all the time, because it constantly uninstalls itself from my laptop for no obvious reason.
I am scanning my mac for viruses right now. I've been having this issue for a while now.

I tried to search for a solution on a few forums, but I wasn't able to find a good solution to the issue.

Any advice or people who have experienced the same?

Comment: *Help!* My Blender has become self aware!

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 3):

Well, Blender is not "installed" on Mac. As shown here https://www.blender.org/download/ on the Blender's download page and as shown in the below snapshot, Blender's mac OS version is a zip/compressed folder. So on mac it has to be deleted not "uninstalled" to be removed, so most probably after downloading it you deleted the folder where it was downloaded (Downloads, Desktop,...etc) which has the dmg file and everything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do your other files get deleted randomly? If so, I would reinstall macOS or buy a new computer.

As @tak mentioned, one does not "install" blender on macOS. So, if you want to protect blender from being deleted, lock the file:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That casual *"buy a new computer"* tho. k. Is this a thing for people with macs?

Comment: @iKlsR Nah. Even if he were running windows I would recommend this. If your computer will randomly delete your files **you should buy a new computer**